# Receiving field values from all enum members

Tags: java, enums

I am struggling with java enums. Due to task assumptions enum values must contain hyphens. I've found out that enum values cannot have such character in its name so i decided to move the correct names as enum fields.

Let's assume that my enum class looks like this.

```
public enum Locale{
    PL("PL-pl"),
    DE("DE-de"),
    EN("EN-en");

    public final String locale;

    private Locale(String locale) {
        this.locale= locale;
    }
}
```

What i want to achive is to get all field values as array **["PL-pl","DE-de","EN-en"]**

For the enum values its easy

```
Locale[] yourEnums = Locale.class.getEnumConstants();
```

, but I think I searched whole internet and couldn't find solution for my problem.

Comment: `String[] locales = Stream.of(Locale.values()).map(loc -> loc.locale).toArray(String[]::new);`.

Comment: Note there's no reason to use `Locale.class.getEnumConstants()` in this case. All `enum` classes implicitly have a static `values()` method that returns an array of all constants.

Comment: @Slaw
Thank you it worked! Can't belive i missed that...

Comment: Side note: Maybe your example `Locale` enum was created only for this question - but I would give it a different name, to avoid potential clashes with core Java's [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enum value in Java is an object. An object is an instance of a type. In this case, the type is the enum, ("Locale",) so the enum values are instances of that type, in other words, each enum value is of type "Locale". Java guarantees that there will only be a fixed set of instances, one instance for each value declared in the enum.

When you declare a constructor and fields in an `enum`, these become part of each instance. So, each one of the locales you have declared will have an extra member of type `String` which you call `locale`.

Knowing that, and also knowing that to get all instances, we can use `Locale.values()`, your answer is:

```
for( var instance : Locale.values() )
    System.out.println( instance.locale );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Mike Nakis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132913/642706) is correct. I can clarify a bit more.

Let's change the names in the original code, for clarity.

As [commented by andrewJames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76132833/receiving-field-values-from-all-enum-members#comment134264325_76132833), Java bundles a commonly used class named `Locale`. So let's change your enum name to be more specific, something like `LocaleCode`.

And change the field name to be more specific: `code`.

The `code` field holding the `String` object should be private, to prevent inadvertent re-assignment to another object. Add a getter method to access that string.

For fun, we can add a convenience method to return a [`java.util.Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#ObtainingLocale) object matching our stored code string. By the way, the order of language and culture in your string codes seems to be the reverse of conventional/standard order (but I am no expert).

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Locale;

public enum LocaleCode
{
    PL( "PL-pl" ),
    DE( "DE-de" ),
    EN( "EN-en" );

    // Member field
    private final String code;

    // Constructor
    private LocaleCode ( String code )
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    // Getter method for private field.
    public String getCode ( )
    {
        return code;
    }

    // Convenience method for obtaining a `java.util.Locale` object for this code.
    public Locale getLocale ( )
    {
        …
    }
}
```

You asked:

> What i want to achive is to get all field values as array ["PL-pl","DE-de","EN-en"]

Loop through each of the enum objects, interrogating for its field value, and collect.

You said:

> For the enum values its easy: `Locale[] yourEnums = Locale.class.getEnumConstants();`

Just call `MyEnumClass.values()` for an array of all the enum objects in the order of their declaration. This special method is *not* well-documented, hidden as a mention in Javadoc for [`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)). To quote:

> All the constants of an `enum` class can be obtained by calling the implicit `public static T[] values()` method of that class.

```java
int count = LocaleCode.values().length;
String[] codes = new String[ count ];
LocaleCode[] values = LocaleCode.values();
for ( int index = 0 ; index < values.length ; index++ )
{
    LocaleCode localeCode = values[ index ];
    codes[ index ] = localeCode.getCode();
}
System.out.println( "codes = " + Arrays.toString( codes ) );
```

> codes = [PL-pl, DE-de, EN-en]

More briefly using streams and method reference.

```java
String[] codes =
        Arrays
                .stream( LocaleCode.values() )
                .map( LocaleCode :: getCode )
                .toList()
                .toArray( new String[ 0 ] );
```

> codes = [PL-pl, DE-de, EN-en]